# OpenALPR Compiled for Android Usage

Tags: android, shared-libraries, openalpr

I have follow this tutorial for Android Compilation :
https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr/wiki/Android-compilation

I used the script provided.
I managed to compile and got the libraries with some hardships, of course.

My questions are:

1. It is specified that in Android.mk, there are liblept.so and libtess.so. Also need path specified for openCv.mk. My question is where to get them ? The openCv.mk maybe will come from OpenCV4Android, but what about liblept.so and libtess.so ? I didn't see it mentioned in the tutorial.
2. After I got them, then which one I have to put to where in the Android Studio ?

I'm confused here.
If someone have experienced it before then please enlighten me.

Thank you.

Comment: You at least got the reference app to compile/run? https://github.com/sujaybhowmick/OpenAlprDroidApp as it appears to have  those libraries liblept.so and libtess.so which seem to be from the Tesseract OCR project

Comment: Hmmm, will try that. But, I'm not sure even if I just copy paste the liblept.so and libtess.so, it will just work right away. Anyway, It's worth to try.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I already clone and try it. But it looks like the structure is different. Beside liblept.so and libtess.so, he is using another .so that I dont have. My structure is more similar to it's example about openalpr-droidapp-native, but the readme has no explanation at all. Thx for your suggestion anyway.